# Proving the correctness of the following Hoare triple, $\{a[i] ≥ 0\} a[i] := a[i] + a[j] \{a[i] ≥ a[j]\}$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

How can I prove the correctness of the following Hoare triple, $\{a[i] ≥ 0\} a[i] := a[i] + a[j] \{a[i] ≥ a[j]\}$

Is it just enough to show $(a[i] + a[j] ≥ a[j] ∧ (i ≠ j))$ to prove it or do I have to show it leads to the precondition?

I think that I need consider all cases for i, j somehow.

Is this how I could do it?

$$\{a[i] > 0\} => \\
\{a[i] + a[j] ≥ a[j]\} \\
a[i] := a[i] + a[j] \\
\{a[i] ≥ a[j]\}$$

Comment: This is not really a hoare logic problem.  Most of the logic of this problem has to be done in another language.  The problem, as stated, isn't solvable in hoare logic.

Comment: I think you want to convert the precondition into $a[i] + a[j] \ge a[j]$ and then apply the basic assignment axiom.

Comment: @DanielV Would you be able to show to that? (As in write it out formally)?

Comment: All the $j=i$ or $j \ne i$ stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: Going from $a[i] \ge 0$ to $a[i] + a[j] \ge a[j]$ isn't Hoare logic, so that can't be written out formally in Hoare logic (unless you somehow have a procedural definition of $\ge$).  And establishing $\{a[i] + a[j] \ge a[j]\} ~ a[i] := a[i] + a[j] ~ \{a[i] \ge a[j]\}$ is literally just one application of 1 axiom.

Comment: @DanielV So my edited answer would suffice for considering all cases of $i$ and $j$?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably how I would write it (can't use latex b/c it is too wide):

```
              Logic                   
 -------------------------------      ------------------------------------------------------ Assignment
 a[i] ≥ 0 ⇒ a[i] + a[j] ≥ a[j]       {a[i] + a[j] ≥ a[j]} a[i] := a[i] + a[j] {a[i] ≥ a[j]}
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Precondition Strengthening
            {a[i] ≥ 0} a[i] := a[i] + a[j] {a[i] ≥ a[j]}
```